# How to use comic fonts in LaTex (TexStudio with MikTex)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, miktex, texstudio, windows

I have a template that needs the comic font that is not working anymore (I need to write an article according to this template, so it is not an option to use another font or change the template). I compiled the same template on my old computer, and it worked fine, but when switching to a new windows 10 computer it does not work anymore. Can anyone help me get the fonts installed properly? In the LaTex template I have received, the following is everything before the actual text. Packages and commands commented out are things I have tried that did not work.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%%% remove comment delimiter ('%') and select language if required
% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % font encoding
\usepackage{amssymb} % extended symbol collection
\usepackage{amsmath} % mathematical formulas
\usepackage{caption} % figure and table caption
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} % figures
\usepackage{siunitx} % unit \SI{}{}
\usepackage{url} % web site
\usepackage{mathptmx} % change text and formular to times
\usepackage{natbib} % bibliography
\usepackage{apalike} % bibliography style
\usepackage{hyperref} % hightlight reference
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % prevent hyphenation 
\usepackage{ulem} % strike the words
\usepackage{indentfirst} % indent the first paragragh
\usepackage{sectsty} % change section font size
\usepackage{secdot} % add a dot after the number of section
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} % remove the indenation in footnote
\usepackage{color} % font color
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for header
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[utf8ttf]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{ttfucs}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 top=22mm,
 bottom=34mm,
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm 
 }

%% FORMAT PAGES AND FONT
\setlength{\columnsep}{8mm} % space between two column
\setlength{\columnwidth}{81mm}
\headheight = 12.5mm
\headsep = 32pt % change the space between the header line and the text block
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus4pt minus4pt} % set distance between two paragraphs
\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont} % set font size of 12pt and line spacing of 14pt
\setlength{\parindent}{6mm} % set paragraph indenting as 6mm

\sectionfont{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt plus2pt minus2pt}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt plus2pt minus2pt}\selectfont}
\subsubsectionfont{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt plus2pt minus2pt}\selectfont}

%\DeclareTruetypeFont{comic}{comic}

\newcommand*{\cmcsans}{\fontfamily{comic}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcmcsans}{\cmcsans}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BELOW FOR EDITOR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1} % page can be specified by hand
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ABOVE FOR EDITOR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% ADD HEADER ON THE TITLE PAGE
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
\chead{{\hspace{4cm}
\textcmcsans{Proceeding of the 13\textsuperscript{th} International Conference on bla bla bla 
\\
\hspace{4cm} bla bla bla bla.}}}
\lhead{\fontsize{22}{26}\selectfont \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\textit{SAMPLE MAT}}}}
\rhead{\thepage \hspace{15pt}}
}
%% ADD HEADER ON EVERY PAGE AFTER THE TITLE PAGE
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{{\hspace{4cm} 
\textcmcsans{Proceeding of the 13\textsuperscript{th} International Conference on bla bla bla 
\\ 
\hspace{4cm} bla bla bla bla.}}}
\lhead{\fontsize{22}{26}\selectfont \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\textit{SAMPLE MAT}}}}
\rhead{\thepage \hspace{15pt}}

%%%%%%%%%%%% TITLE AND AUTHOR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{\fontsize{20}{24}\vspace{-20pt}
\textbf{Guidelines for Preparation of Manuscripts}
}

\author{
Author 01, first name, surname, \textit{Affiliation 01} \textcolor{blue}{\underline{e-mail}}
\vspace{10pt}

Author 02, first name, surname, \textit{Affiliation 02} \textcolor{blue}{\underline{e-mail}}
} 
\date{}

\begin{document}
%% ADD ABSTRACT
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\fontsize{9}{24}\textbf{ABSTRACT}

\vspace{14pt}
\hspace{6mm}
Authors of papers have to type these in a form suitable for direct photographic reproduction by the publisher. In order to ensure uniform style throughout the volume, all the papers have to be prepared strictly according to the instructions set below, which essentially follow the ITTC format. 

\vspace{14pt} 
\hspace{6mm}
The abstract should be a brief description of the scope of the paper, not exceeding 100 words in length.

\vspace{14pt}
\fontsize{9}{14}\textbf{Keywords:} 
\textit{at least 3 suitable keywords for indexing purposes}
\vspace{14pt}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\section{INTRODUCTION}
 \bla bla bla 
\end{document}
```

This \cmcsans-command is used to make text on the header. As I said, this worked fine on my old computer, but on the Windows 10 machine I get the following warnings when I compile with pdflatex (and the pdf contains only squares where the text should be):

```
...
...
pdflatex.exe (file C:/Users/erva/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/truetype/comic.ttf): glyph `t' not found
pdflatex.exe (file C:/Users/erva/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/truetype/comic.ttf): glyph `y' not found><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fon
```

I tried to do what is suggested here: http://william.famille-blum.org/software/latexttf/index.html but it did not work. The font-related files seems to have been copied correctly, but still my file fails to compile properly.

Does anyone understand what is wrong here, and what the ***glyph `y' not found*** warning means? And how to fix this?

I also discovered that if I change "comic" in the definition of \cmcsans above, I will get text, but with "standard" fonts. For example, putting "test" there, I get the following warning: Font shape "T1/test/m/n' undefined(Font) using T1/cmr/m/n' instead". However, with "comic" I get just square boxes. This makes me suspect that the font is actually there and is found by LaTex, but that there is something wrong with it. With the new Windows 10 machine, no matter what I do I don't seem to be able to fix it, but on the old PC I did not have to do anything special. Could it be that Windows has changed anything with regards to these fonts when upgrading to 10?

Any help is much appreciated, and I am really struggeling to sort this out.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) could you please post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) Also, what install of LaTeX did you have on your old PC? I can see that your new one uses MiKTeX which doesn't come with everything (compared to TeXlive that does)

Comment: Did you think of running `updmap.exe --verbose` from the command line (both as administrator and as user)?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Last thing first: Bernard, I have run this command (both as user and admin) several times. It does not help.

Comment: Thorbjørn: old installation of LaTex was also MikTex. Both versions were MikTex 2.9, and both used Texstudio (I guess that is not the issue anyway). I update the post above with the LaTex template, including all packages etc...

Comment: As I also updated in the original post: I also discovered that if I change "comic" in the definition of \cmcsans above, I will get text, but with "standard" fonts. For example, putting "test" there, I get the following warning: Font shape "T1/test/m/n' undefined(Font) using T1/cmr/m/n' instead". However, with "comic" I get just square boxes. This makes me suspect that the font is actually there and is found by LaTex, but that there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the updated Comic Sans MS font in Windows 10 (maybe earlier). If you take the font file (comic.ttf) from old system (Windows 7's version is ok) and put it in the same folder with your TeX-file (or somewhere where TeX can find it), then everything should work.